# How to determine if an Google Optimize server side experiment is working correctly?

Tags: google-optimize

Currently, we are in the process of setting up a server-side AB testing using Google Optimize.

We have done the implementation as per the following:
https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments

I noticed that when the following command is executed that the _gaexp cookie is not getting set correctly i.e the experiment ID is not appearing in the _gaexp cookie.

```
 ga('set', 'exp', '$experimentId.$variationId');
```

I wanted to know if this was normal behavior for GO based server-side AB testing.

Any help would be much appreciated.